# How to find the fourth power of a matrix just using Cayley Hamilton?

Tags: matrices, cayley-hamilton

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&2\\-1&2&-1\\1&-1&2\end{bmatrix}$$

I am supposed to find $A^4$.

I tried to find the characteristic equation and got

$$-x^3+6x^2-8x+3=0$$

From here I can go the long route and multiply by $x$ the equation and solve the other side for $x^4$ but it felt time consuming. Is there any other way to proceed?

Comment: Why not just multiply the $4$ (identical) matrices together ? This requires probably less effort than determining the characteristic equation.

Comment: You can even save a step by squaring twice.

Comment: Other method: diagonalize.

Comment: Have a look at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3517846)

Comment: Are you sure that the value of $a_{13}$ is really $2$? I think it was probably intended to be $1$.

Comment: @Sean Roberson The title says "using Cayley Hamilton".

Comment: @Peter I don't understand, that seems like it would take ages. Multiplying A.A.A.A

Comment: Squaring a 3x3-matrix should be absolutely routine - even without a calculator, if the entries are so small in absolute values as here.

Comment: @Peter jesus mgee, thanks copy paste I accept ur answer